# User defined function (def) in Python 3.2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am currently reading "[How to think like a computer scientist: Learning with Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/)" (Green Tea Press, January 2002.)

I can't make any define functions work. I have copied it exactly as it is in the book, but it is not working. What at I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
def printParity(x):
    if (x)%2 == 0:
        print (x), ("is even")
    else:
        print (x), ("is odd")
```

It just prints the (x) input rather that (x) is odd or even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
def printParity(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x, "is even")
    else:
        print(x, "is odd")
```

Your statement `print (x), ("is even")`

is actually making a tuple, as can be seen at the console:

```
>>> x=2
>>> print (x), ("is even")
2
(None, 'is even')
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, `print` is a function, not a statement. Use a Python 3 tutorial.

```
def printParity(x):
    print("{0} is {1}".format(x, "odd" if x % 2 else "even"))
```

As DSM points out, your code is making a tuple that evaluates the result of `print(x)` as its first element (and since `print()` doesn't return anything, that result is `None`), and `"is even"` as its second element. However, it doesn't do anything with that tuple, so nothing visible happens (and the unnamed tuple will soon be garbage-collected). The only thing visible is the "side effect" of the function call `print(x)` which of course outputs the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes in that code snippets. Since you are programming in Python, you have to make sure that every code block is indented. That is how you define code-blocks in Python - by indentation, not by using parenthesis.

Also, (x) does not mean anything. It will just print x or whatever is there instead.

Try this:

```
def printParity(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print (x, "is even")
    else:
        print (x, "is odd")
```

Comment: @vaidik It is possible to edit answers if they have proven to be misleading.

Comment: I think that is possible @glglgl.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parentheses around your variable name. Also, you can use format strings to make your printed output a bit clearer

```
def printParity(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print ("%s is even" % x)
    else:
        print ("%s is odd" % x)
```

Comment: Becaue the OP is using Python 3, this will give a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Just to clarify: @DSM 's comment here is obsolete due to a edit which happened afterwards.